# Enumerate content in custom view template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am very new in Drupal. I am using Drupal 7.
I would like to create a custom rendering for a view I have created. 
Thanks to many posts found on the internet I have already done the following steps:

1. Created a content type with Title and URL (it simulate a link list)
2. Added 4 items of this content type
3. Created a view which return items of my content type unsorted
4. Thanks to the Theme Information link I have created a template named `views-view--xxxx--page.tpl.php` where xxxx is the name of my view.
5. I have added the following code to the TPL file

> ```
> <article id="node-123456">
>     <header>
>         <h1>Sample Title</h1>
>     </header>
>     <div class="content">
>     </div>
>     <footer> </footer>
> </article>
> ```

And this works perfectly because I am seeing the `Sample Title` text when navigating on the page. I want now to enumerate the list of content item produced by the view but I dont know how to enumerate them. I have tried with

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <li><?php print $view->render_field('field_url', $id);?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Drupal!

Use row level templating in template suggestion and follow exactly the same markup so your code should look like the following

```
<article id="">
    <header>
        <h1><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <footer> </footer>
</article>
```

It will follow the same markup for each row.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Do you mean choose a template on the section named "Row Style Output"? In the suggestions there is a template named "--xxxx--page.tpl.php". Does this means that I have to create a template starting with the dash?

Comment: row level template basically style each of your row. If you want to add markup to your views row go ahead and copy exactly the same file and clear the cache

Comment: Sorry but did not understand your suggestion. Could you please be more specific? I cant understand if I have to change the view name or the code somewhere. Thanks

Comment: A view is a list of rows like
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

If you want to markup your individual row then override that template and add your markup. You don't have to change view name just pick row template from template suggestion and add your markup there.
Remember markup will get applied on each row!

Comment: Ok. I have got it now. Thanks. Unfortunately my theme does not have a row style template. In fact if I click on the Row Style Output hyperlink I get the message "This display has no row style theming information"

Comment: You should use fields instead of content in views setting up above. change from content to fields then you can override it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18227/discussion-between-shabir-and-lorenzo).